# work with one variable in changed enviorment

Tags: php

My code require 2 function and each one of them need $id value.
The point is how i can specific equals the $id to the value needed in each function that after the function work it will be equals to default number as i set in the top of the page.
i work hard for this and searched a lot and not  seen a answer. thanks guys
i tried:

```
    $id = 1;
function test1($id=2){echo $id."response 2";}
function test2($id){echo $id."response 2 but should be response 1";}
```

how can i do it?

Comment: 1. Your functions need a name 2. How do you call them? + Can't reproduce that the second function prints 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the check inside the function based on the $id parameter.

```
function some($id){
  switch($id){
    case 1: doSomething(); 
    break; 
    case 2: doSomethingElse(); 
    break; 
  } 
}
```